# VB.NET Fading out button properly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, picturebox, fade

How do you fade out/in a button in VB.NET properly? I can fadeout/in labels using:

```
Controls(i).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, alpha, alpha, alpha)
```

(where `Controls(i)` is a label from a `For` `Next` loop through all controls in `Me.Controls`; `alpha` is the value of the RGB, also from a `For` `Next` loop).

This did *not* work for me with buttons because changing the `ForeColor` leaves the rest of the buttons' UIs visible!

So, the way I'm trying uses a saved `Resource` image of the button (from a screenshot) and creates a faded in/out version to be displayed as the image in a `PictureBox`:

```
Public Function SetImageOpacity(ByVal imgPic As Image, ByVal imgOpac As Double) As Image
    Dim bmpPic As New Bitmap(imgPic.Width, imgPic.Height)
    Dim grPic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpPic)
    Dim imgAtt As New ImageAttributes()
    Dim cmxPic As New ColorMatrix()
    cmxPic.Matrix33 = imgOpac
    imgAtt.SetColorMatrix(cmxPic, ColorMatrixFlag.[Default], ColorAdjustType.Bitmap)
    grPic.DrawImage(imgPic, New Rectangle(178, 144, bmpPic.Width, bmpPic.Height), imgPic.Width, imgPic.Height, imgPic.Width, imgPic.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAtt)
    grPic.Dispose()
    imgAtt.Dispose()
    Return bmpPic
End Function
```

(where `imgPic` is the `Resource` image of the button, and `imgOpac` is the opacity on a scale of 1 to 0, where 0 is transparent).

I then use this image to set my `PictureBox`'s image:

```
picbox.Image = SetImageOpacity(My.Resources.Nextbutton, 1)
```

However, I get a glitch where, even though the `PictureBox` is located at coordinates `178, 144`, the image it is showing is displayed at the left edge of the form (i.e. wrong X coordinate), with the Y coordinate correct!

I have a feeling it may lie with my call of `.DrawImage(`...`)` (at line 8 of the function) - but [the MSDN docs on this subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142046(v=vs.110).aspx) are very unclear to me.

Please link if this has been asked before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates in the Graphics `grPic` are **client** coords relative to the image itself, not the Form.  So (0, 0) is the top left of the image regardless of where that image ends up being displayed in some kind of control.

Try changing it to (0, 0):

```
grPic.DrawImage(imgPic, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmpPic.Width, bmpPic.Height), imgPic.Width, imgPic.Height, imgPic.Width, imgPic.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAtt)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just use a for loop to change the opacity of the button control from 1 to 0 in increments of say .01 ?

Comment: As I had explained in my answer, this was not working as I intended it to - @Idle_Mind explained the issue with my `SetImageOpacity` sub. Thanks for your answer anyway!